# how to call devise.rb validatable method primitively and prevent double warnings with other gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

i try to follow **RFC** format of email using `validates_email_format_of` gem to check strictly
(
https://github.com/validates-email-format-of/validates_email_format_of)

Thats because `devise.rb`'s `validatable` allow `hoge....@gmail.com` that doesnt follow RFC.

but im using also `devise.rb` so that double errors came up.

i want to avoid this using like

```rb
validate self-made-method

def self-made-method
    # psedo-code 
    if email.present? && Devise::Models::Validatabl.hoge_method(email).valid?
          errors.add("somthing")
    end
end
```

[image: double errors]

but i couldnt find such a method to `devise.rb`.

do you have any idea to avoid this situation.

in short i want to call `validatable` rawly i guess

https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Validatable#assert_validations_api!-class_method

Answer (score 0):

i finally import and apply to my original-model.rb to validate

and use original validation validates_email . two of them are possible to co-exist

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, case_sensitive: true, if: :will_save_change_to_email?
validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
validates_length_of       :password, within: 8..72, allow_blank: true
```

extract

```rb
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```

```
  def validates_email
    if email.present? && ValidatesEmailFormatOf.validate_email_format(email).present?
      errors.add(:email, '不正な値です')
    end
  end
```